# How to use sortedWith() in kotlin?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I am trying to sort that simple list of users by "created". What am I doing wrong?

```
val user1 = User("2019-01-01 17:42:34")
val user2 = User("2019-01-02 17:42:34")
val user3 = User("2019-01-03 17:42:34")
val list = listOf(user2, user3, user1)

list.sortedWith(compareBy {
    LocalDateTime.parse(
        it.created,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    )
})

data class User(val created: String = "")
```

Comment: What does the compiler say? What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: as a side-note: you should add a `DateTime`-property to your `User` and supply an appropriate `String`-constructor instead. Otherwise you keep on parsing the (same!) `DateTime` in the comparison several times (which is probably not what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. The problem here is that `sortedWith` returns a **new** list with the results of the sorting! Check the documentation:

> Returns a list of all elements sorted according to the specified [comparator].
>   The sort is *stable*. It means that equal elements preserve their order relative to each other after sorting.

So if you want to sort the collection itself you need to use a `MutableList` and `sortWith`:

```
val list = mutableListOf(User("2019-01-01 17:42:34"), User("2019-01-02 17:42:34"), User("2019-01-03 17:42:34"))
list.sortWith(compareBy {
    LocalDateTime.parse(
            it.created,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
})
```

Comment: You probably don't want to assign `Unit` (result of `sortWith`) to `result`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you are right, I forgot to remove it from my original code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sortedWith` function returns a new list with sorted elements without modifying the original collection. You probably want to use `sortWith` function of `MutableList` that sorts the original collection.